# set cookie values dynamically for incoming user in ecommerce site

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to show recently viewed items in my site in php.For which i was thinking to make use of cookies,according to which i want to store what user is clicking in a db with cookie values the users have.Now I dont know how to generate cookies dynamically for one pc or device,when user clicks items on my site while navigating through....
Please guide me on how to put cookie values in a db along with product details in database,so that later when they come to my site they should get recently visited products on basis of the cookie values in my db..